# <div> с автозаполнением свободного пространства

Tags: css, html, веб-программирование

Есть 2 div`a, один справа имеет строгую ширину - 300px(например), а второй слева должен подстраиваться и заполнять остальную площадь.

Снизу два скрина, где див уходит на другой ряд и не заполняет область.
Не использовать JS, только HTML and CSS

```
[![не заполняет][1]][1]
```

[image: падает вниз]

CSS:

```
body{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.main{
    display: inline-block;
}
#white{
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

#left{
        background-color:#a8a8a8;
        height: 100%;
}
#rightRed{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}

#green{
    background-color: green;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;

}
#blue{
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;

}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style32.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="left" class="main">
Сірий блок
</div>

<div id="rightRed" class="main">

  <div id="green">Green block</div>

    <div id="blue">Blue block
      <div id="white">White</div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю изменения только для 1 блока:

```
#left {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 300px); /* высчитывает ширину левого вычитая ширину правого */
  float: left; /* т.к. есть `float: right`, то нужен и `left` */ 
}
```

И получим следующий результат:

```css
body {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
}

#left {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  float: left;
}

#rightRed {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="left" class="main">
    Сірий блок
  </div>

  <div id="rightRed" class="main">

    <div id="green">Green block</div>

    <div id="blue">Blue block
      <div id="white">White</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо, даже не знал, что есть такая функция calc ))

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    width: 1000px; /* ширина материнского блока */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.main{  
  display: inline-block;
}
#white{
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

#left{
  width: 70%; /* остальная шырина */        
  background-color:#a8a8a8;
        height: 100%;
}
#rightRed{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px; /* тоесть 30% от ширины материнского блока */
    float: right;
}

#green{
  
  background-color: green;
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;

}
#blue{
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 20%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style32.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="left" class="main">
Сірий блок
</div>

<div id="rightRed" class="main">

  <div id="green">Green block</div>

    <div id="blue">Blue block
      <div id="white">White</div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```